# Curved line in formulas

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, boxes

I want to write a column of formulas, but with a curved line on the left side, like on that picture. How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `MnSymbol` and its `\lwavy`, `\rwavy`, `\lWavy`, `\rWavy`  extensible delimiters, with `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
 \usepackage{empheq}
\DeclareLeftDelimiter{\lwavy}
\DeclareRightDelimiter{\rwavy}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left =\boldsymbol\empheqlwavy\quad]{align*}
    (a+b)^2 & = a^2 + 2ab + b^2; \\
    (a-b)^2 & = a^2 - 2ab + b^2; \\
    (a+b)(a-b) & = a^2 - b^2; \\
    (a + b + c)^2 & = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ca)
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image: examples of wavy lines]

Comment: @Jagath: note it is not compatible with `amssymb` (actually `MnSymbol` replaces it). Theoretically, there's another possibility with `\leftwave` and `rightwave` extensible symbols (much more contrasted) in `mathdesign` but unfortunately,  it produces errors on my system.

Comment: it might be possible to use the mechanism shown here to use *only* the needed symbols: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: @Barbars beeton: In theory, I know how to do that (for instance with `mathabx`). With MnSymbol, there's no `.fd` file, only a `.sty`, and I'm unsure of what's the name of the family  (it seems to be a long name, with a couple of @ inside, and there are 6 subfamilies…).  It should be doable , but certainly requires some time…

Answer (score 3):

Here is something you can try using `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick] 
\draw [decorate, 
      decoration={snake, segment length=10mm, amplitude=2mm}
      ] (0,.5) -- (0,4.5);
  \node [anchor=west] at (1, 4) {$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$};
  \node [anchor=west] at (1, 3) {$(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$};
  \node [anchor=west] at (1, 2) {$(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$};
  \node [anchor=west] at (1, 1) {$(a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ca)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note: You could adjust `segment length=10mm` and `amplitude=2mm` to adjust the curves as required.